# generic htaccess script to make a subdirectory an endpoint by rewriting all sub-subdirectory requests to the subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, endpoint, subdirectory

Is there a `.htaccess` script that I could put into any subdirectory A without modification, which would catch all requests to files in that subdirectory A as well as deeper subdirectories A/* and rewrite it to subdirectory A? The original browser URL should stay intact and again preferably, I'd like to do this without modifying the `.htaccess` script.

Example:

```
domain.com/dir1/dir2            <-- this directory should become the endpoint

domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3       <-- rewrite (keep browser URL intact) to /dir1/dir2

domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4  <-- rewrite (keep browser URL intact) to /dir1/dir2
```

I have this working with the following script, but this script would need me to update it for any directory I put it in....

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dir1/dir2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dir1/dir2/ [L]
```

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding RewriteBase in your attempt. It's unused because your substitution is not relative.

You need to capture the first two subdirectories and substitute them back in e.g. ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2

Answer (score 0):

This rule should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule . /dir1/dir2/ [L]
```

That is match any file/directory in `/dir1/dir2/` other than just `/dir1/dir2/` and rewrite to base of `/dir1/dir2/`.